# How to define a default indexed property for a TObject class in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Given these classes;

```
type TMyItem = class(TObject)
private
  FReference: String;
  FOtherProperty: TObject;
public
  property Reference: String read FReference write FReference;
  property OtherProperty: String read FOtherPropertywrite FOtherProperty;
end;

type TMyListClass = class(TObjectList<TMyItem>)
public
  function IndexOf(const AReference: String): Integer; overload;
end;

function TMyListClass.IndexOf(const AReference: String): Integer;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := -1;
  for I := 0 to Count - 1 do
    if Items[I].Reference = AReference then
    begin
      Result := I;
      break;
    end;
end;

type TMyClass = class(TObject)
private
  FList: TObjectList<TOtherClass>;
public
  property List: TObjectList<TOtherClass> read FList write FList;
end;
```

How do I implement a property/function/enumerator on TMyClass so that instead of this

```
AMyClass.List.Items[AMyClass.List.IndexOf(ARef)].OtherProperty := AOtherObject;
```

I can do this

```
AMyClass[ARef].OtherProperty := AOtherObject;
```

I thought it would be a matter of making a default property, but you can't pass a parameter to a property like you would a function.

EDIT 07/12.

OK. So if I make `List` the `default;`, I believe this would work.

```
AMyClass[AMyClass.IndexOf(ARef)].OtherProperty := AOtherObject;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `default` keyword usage you are thinking of [only works on array properties](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2132_Default_property_must_be_an_array_property_(Delphi)), but your `List` property is not an array property.

To get the kind of syntax you originally asked for:

```
AMyClass[ARef].OtherProperty := ...;
```

You will have to do the following:

```
type
  TMyClass = class(TObject)
  private
    FList: TObjectList<TMyItem>;
    function GetItem(const AReference: String): TMyItem;
    procedure SetItem(const AReference: String; AItem: TMyItem);
  public
    property List: TObjectList<TMyItem> read FList;
    property Item[const AReference: String]: TMyItem read GetItem write SetItem; default;
  end; 

...

function TMyClass.GetItem(const AReference: String): TMyItem;
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Index := FList.IndexOf(AReference);
  if Index = -1 then
    raise EArgumentException.Create('Reference not found');
  Result := FList[Index];
end;

procedure TMyClass.SetItem(const AReference: String; AItem: TMyItem);
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Index := FList.IndexOf(AReference);
  if Index = -1 then
    FList.Add(AItem)
  else
    FList[Index] := AItem;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy. This is the simplest answer. And thanks for adding in the reference check. No doubt I would have got an error related to that at some point in my testing.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a simple task. You can just look at Delphi sources on how to implement default index properties. But if you want to improve this solution you can declare a few default properties that depend on the type of parameters that you will pass. Here is some code:

```
type TMyClass = class(TObject)
  private
    FList: TObjectList<TMyItem>;
    function GetItemByRef(ARef: string): TMyItem; overload;
    function GetItemByRef(AIndex: integer): TMyItem; overload;
  public
    property MyItems[ARef :string] : TMyItem read GetItemByRef; default;
    property MyItems[AIndex :integer] : TMyItem read GetItemByRef; default;
  end;

function TMyClass.GetItemByRef(ARef: string): TMyItem;
begin
  Result := nil;
  for var xItem in FList do
    if xItem.FReference = ARef then begin
      Result := xItem;
      Break;
    end;
end;

function TMyClass.GetItemByRef(AIndex: integer): TMyItem;
begin
  Result := FList[AIndex];
end;
```

Now you can take your items by reference or by ItemIndex and all by default property:

```
procedure DoSomething;
begin
  MyClass['SomeRefString'].OtherProperty := AOtherObject;
  MyClass[5].OtherProperty := AOtherObject;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit. Sorry, I didn't update the page before posting, therefore my answer is pretty much the same as the one of @RemyLebeau.

I'm not sure I understand you right, but you can do something like this

```
type TMyClass = class(TObject)
private
  FList: TMyListClass;

  function  GetOtherProperty(const ARef: String): TObject;
  procedure SetOtherProperty(const ARef: String; AValue: TObject);
public
  property List: TMyListClass read FList write FList;
  property OtherProperty[const ARef: String]: TObject read GetOtherProperty write SetOtherProperty;
end;

...

function TMyClass.GetOtherProperty(const ARef: String): TObject;
begin
  Result := ... ;// find item
  if ( Result <> nil ) then
    Result := Result.OtherProperty;
end;

procedure TMyClass.SetOtherProperty(const ARef: String; AValue: TObject);
  var item: TMyItem;

begin
  item := ... ;// find item
  if ( item <> nil ) then
    item.OtherProperty := AValue;
end;
```

If `TMyItem.FReference` is unique, you may also implement something like `TDictionary<String, TMyItem>` in your `TMyListClass` and return `TMyItem` directly instead of its index

```
TMyListClass = class(TObjectList<TMyItem>)
private
  FItemDic: TDictionary<String, TMyItem>;

  function GetMyItem(const ARef: String): TMyItem;
protected
  procedure Notify(constref AValue: TMyItem; ACollectionNotification: TCollectionNotification); override;
public
  property    ItemsByRef[const ARef: String]: TMyItem read GetMyItem;
  constructor Create();
  destructor  Destroy(); override;
end;

...

procedure TMyListClass.Notify(constref AValue: TMyItem; ACollectionNotification: TCollectionNotification);
begin
  inherited Notify(AValue, ACollectionNotification);

  if ( FItemDic = nil ) then Exit;

  case ( ACollectionNotification ) of
    cnAdded : FItemDic.AddOrSetValue( AValue.Reference, AValue );
    cnRemoved, cnExtracted: FItemDic.Remove( AValue.Reference );
  end;
end;

function TMyListClass.GetMyItem(const ARef: String): TMyItem;
begin
  FItemDic.TryGetValue( ARef, Result );
end;

constructor TMyListClass.Create();
begin
  inherited;
  FItemDic := TDictionary<String, TMyItem>.Create();
end;

destructor TMyListClass.Destroy();
begin
  FreeAndNil(FItemDic);
  inherited Destroy();
end;
```

The code above was written in Lazarus 2.2.2, but it should work in latest Delphi as well.